# React Native navigation.goBack() inside componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to call the `navigation.goBack()` inside `componentDidUpdate`, the backing works however the animation of going back does not. Like the slide effect.

The use case that I have is for implementing an edit screen. Suppose you just edited some items but now when you click update/save you want to go back. In order to catch that update/save event, I am making it a part of the NavigationScreenProp, this is setting the state of the NavigationScreenProp.

Once the header update button is clicked the NavigationScreenProp becomes {isUpdated=true}. This fires the componentDidUpdate event and inside of it I handle saving the data, however the problem occurs when calling the back.
This scenario however works if you create an alert when isUpdated===true and goes back with animation.

Any help or direction would be great help! Thanks!
Also if there is a better way to handle this scenario, please comment :)

Comment: Can you just do the `navigation.goBack()` in the press event handler of update/save? Why go through NavigationScreenProp and componentDidUpdate?

Comment: I’m not using actual events, I’m just changing the value, which fires a event on its own as a navigationprop update which the main body component handles. I want the main body to handle it because I’m doing validation and other stuff. This way the header navbar can be reusable